# Nginx uses both writev() and sendfile()

Tags: linux, nginx, linux-kernel

I noticed that when serving images Nginx is sending images using both writev() when called from a browser such as Firefox, but uses sendfile() to send the image when wgetting the image. Any idea why its using both? I have ' sendfile on ; ' in the config. Can't find a good answer anywhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer, the reason it was using writev() when using a web browser was because the browser sent headers requesting gzip. I disabled gzip on the server and now images are sent using sendfile() to wget, curl, and browsers. Mission accomplished!

---

```
#gzip  on;
#gzip_comp_level 9;
#gzip_types *;
```

Comment: You should assign a list of types you want to compress with gzip. It is still useful to compress static and dynamic HTML, CSS etc.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, this server is only used for image serving so that shouldn't be needed.

Comment: Also TLS will require using `writev` since (at least for now) kernel can not encrypt data for you.